# Changing an awkward array's values' type from float to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, awkward-array

I have an awkward array of type float and I need it to be of type int. Something equivalent to the following numpy snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import awkward as ak

arr = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
arr = arr.astype(int)

arr2 = ak.Array(np.array([1., 2., 3.]))
arr2 = arr2.???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an awkward array, `arr`, where:

```
>>> arr.type
20 * float64
```

You can simply use [`ak.values_astype`](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.values_astype.html):

```
>>> arr = ak.values_astype(arr, "int64")
>>> arr
20 * int64
```

Comment: Hint to @HEP N008: you should accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score -1):

this is how you could change all values within an array from *float* to *int*:

```
# Example array
arr_float = [3.45, 5.6, 3.89, 10.1]

# to integer values 
arr_int = [int(n) for n in arr_float] # this is a list comprehension
arr_int
>>> [3, 5, 3, 10] # float values to integer get always rounded down to whole number
```

Alternatively, you make the the array an numpy array and proceed like in your question:

```
import numpy as np

# Example array
arr_float = [3.45, 5.6, 3.89, 10.1]

# to numpy array
arr_np = np.array(arr_float)

arr_np.astype(int)
>>> array([ 3,  5,  3, 10])
```

This would be a function that is callable whenever you need to change:

```
# Function changing float values to integer values
def to_int(input_array):
    return [int(n) for n in input_array]

# Example array
arr_float = [3.86, 2.9999, 9.46, 3.00013, 8.56]

to_int(arr_float)
>>> [3, 2, 9, 3, 8]
```

Comment: The question was asking about the Awkward Array library; I've edited it to make that clearer.

Comment: My bad. Wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: The other issue with this code, from my usage standpoint, is that it would take way too long. Looping in Python is very slow, while proper broadcasting is pretty quick; though what you posted would certainly work for shorter arrays.